# ORACLE OFSA home screen

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would need help with ofsaa application, I would like to change home screen when you login to application, currently it directly goes to "Financial Services Applications", but I would like default home screen where user has a chance to select his own home screen.

I was told that this is under CONFIG_OWNER schema, and that I should only remove one record in table. But I don't know which table.

Thanks in advance. 
Br, Aljaž.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the records in cssms_usr_startup_page table of the configuration schema. locate the user id and remove the row.

Answer (score 0):

This table cssms_usr_startup_page  doesn't have any record in Version 8110.
However, you can refer to the Oracle support team on this. Kindly update the solution here as well.

I am working on OFSAA around 2+ years but haven't faced such issue.